# Outbound leg cancelled – Can I get a partial refund?

Tags: cancellations, compensation, refunds, passenger-rights, ec261

I have a trip booked in November with the

- outbound journey on Austrian Airlines from Zurich via Vienna to Nuremberg,

and the

- return on Lufthansa from Nuremberg via Frankfurt to Zurich.

I have been informed that the flight I was supposed to take from Zurich to Vienna has been cancelled. I could take the earlier flight, but that would result in a six-hour layover in Vienna.

As far as I am aware, I am eligible for a refund of my entire ticket due to this flight cancellation (correct me if I'm wrong). However, could I also opt to only fly the return journey, and get (roughly) half of my ticket value back? Or would the ticket be re-priced in this case for a one-way journey NUE-FRA-ZRH, which as of now would cost me significantly more than I have originally paid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As far as I am aware, I am eligible for a refund of my entire ticket due to this flight cancellation

Correct

> However, could I also opt to only fly the return journey, and get (roughly) half of my ticket value back?

That's unlikely to happen since LH would have to reprice the ticket which is complicated and will NOT result in a 50% refund. I'm guessing your options are to either change the outgoing flight or cancel the whole thing. If in doubt, call LH and ask.

Have you considered taking the train instead? Deutsche Bahn operates the IC bus to Munich and there is plenty of trains from there to Nuernberg. You can probably do the whole thing in about 5-6 hours for less than 30 Euro each way.

Comment: I had originally booked a direct ZRH-NUE-ZRH on Swiss which was cancelled two weeks ago. When I saw the option of routing through VIE/FRA with short layovers, I asked them to rebook me instead of a refund since I thought it would be more convenient than the train, even though I would not be saving a lot of time anymore.

But you are right, at this point just giving up on flying and taking the train would probably be the better option.

BTW the EC train to Munich is operational again and will be ramped up to six times a day in December at which point the bus will be discontinued.

Comment: The EC certainly saves you the hassle from transferin in MUnich from Bus to Train (ca. 10 minute walk). I took the bus about a month ago and managed to get a front seat on the upper deck directly behind the windshield, that was a nice trip!

Comment: Walk? I've always taken the S-Bahn as suggested by the Bahn website, I didn't realize it was actually this close...

Comment: It's easily walkable and IMO a lot easier than taking the S-Bahn. Just head to Arnulfstrasse and you can get into the train station through the side door.